# Ngram query for 'I am a Japanese.'

Tags: discussion

Would you help me come up with the query for this in Google Ngram?

I would like to know the use frequency of 'I am a Japanese,' not 'I am a Japanese sailor' or 'I am a Japanese citizen,' or any of such sentences in which Japanese is followed by other words. Hence I punched in ((I'm a Japanese) - (I'm a Japanese+_NOUN_)). This came back with negative figures. What query is supposed to be used?

Comment: The numbers are so vanishingly small, I think you might be best off just actually looking at the Google Books results.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that "(I'm a Japanese+NOUN)" will give you the sum of the frequencies of the string "I'm a Japanese" and the string "NOUN", which is not what you want.

In the Google Ngram Viewer, [part of speech tags](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info) are marked with underscore characters. To use one as a placeholder for a word, you put underscores on both sides, like this: _NOUN_.

Note that with part of speech tags, you can only look at 1-, 2- or 3-grams, not 4- or 5-grams.

So you won't be able to look for "I am a Japanese _NOUN_".

One thing you can do is look at "(a Japanese) - (a Japanese _NOUN_)".

You can also use wildcard search with "I am a Japanese *" to see what kind of words most frequently follow this string. One of the top results is "I am a Japanese and", where it is not followed directly by a noun, although I suppose this could include sentences with unwanted structures like "I am a Japanese and American citizen".

_END_ is a part-of-speech tag, so it has the same restrictions for length: you can search for "a Japanese _END_", but not for anything longer.

Comment: I added a comment above to edit my query as ((I'm a Japanese) - (I'm a Japanese+_NOUN_). Sorry for the confusion. I wonder if there is a way to tell the Ngram it's the end of the sentence. "I am a Japanese (something)" with 'something' being the sentence end marker.

Comment: How couldn't I think of simple (Japanese_NOUN)? This clinches how frequently Japanese as a noun was used. This does not address my search for the frequency of the sentence, but I wanted to see the use of the word as a noun.

Comment: The google ngrams search syntax is deceptive. It looks simple, but usually doesn't do what you expect and is much more constrained than you'd expect. Look at the 'help' page for it.

Comment: Now I realized (Japanese_NOUN) included the Japanese language. Silly me.